# Discord python embed won't update numerical value

Tags: discord, discord.py, embed

So, from this image, you can see that this won't update the value of "wins" or "losses" despite the `wins += 1` and `losses += 1` addition I have under each `if`/`elif` statement.
[image: example]

**Here is the code:**

```py
## Rock paper scissors
@bot.command(name="rps", description="Play rock paper scissors against the bot!", pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.user)
async def rps(ctx):    
    em1 = discord.Embed(title="Rock Paper Scissors", description="What do you pick?", color=discord.Color.blue())
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=em1)
    rock = ""
    paper = ""
    scissors = "✂️"
    options = ["", "", "✂️"]
    await msg.add_reaction(rock)
    await msg.add_reaction(paper)
    await msg.add_reaction(scissors)

    def check(reaction, user):
      return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in options 
    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)

    random_number = random.randint(0,2)
    computer_pick = options[random_number]
    wins = 0
    losses = 0
    desc = "Wins: " + str(wins) + "\n" + "Losses: " + str(losses)

    emtie = discord.Embed(title="It's a tie!", description=desc, color=discord.Color.teal())
    emlose = discord.Embed(title="You lost!", description=desc, color=discord.Color.red())
    emwin = discord.Embed(title="You win!", description=desc, color=discord.Color.green())

    

    if str(reaction.emoji) == rock and computer_pick == options[0]:
      await ctx.send("You picked: " + rock + "\n" + "Computer picked: " + rock)
      await ctx.send(embed=emtie)
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == rock and computer_pick == options[1]:
      losses += 1
      await ctx.send("You picked: " + rock + "\n" + "Computer picked: " + paper)
      await ctx.send(embed=emlose)
      
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == rock and computer_pick == options[2]:
      wins += 1
      await ctx.send("You picked: " + rock + "\n" + "Computer picked: " + scissors)
      await ctx.send(embed=emwin)
      
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == paper and computer_pick == options[0]:
      wins += 1
      await ctx.send("You picked: " + paper + "\n" + "Computer picked: " + rock)
      await ctx.send(embed=emwin)
    
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == paper and computer_pick == options[1]:
      await ctx.send("You picked: " + paper + "\n" + "Computer picked: " + paper)
      await ctx.send(embed=emtie)
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == paper and computer_pick == options[2]:
      losses += 1
      await ctx.send("You picked: " + paper + "\n" + "Computer picked: " + scissors)
      await ctx.send(embed=emlose)
      
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == scissors and computer_pick == options[0]:
      losses += 1
      await ctx.send("You picked: " + scissors + "\n" + "Computer picked: " + rock)
      await ctx.send(embed=emlose)
      
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == scissors and computer_pick == options[1]:
      wins += 1
      await ctx.send("You picked: " + scissors + "\n" + "Computer picked: " + paper)
      await ctx.send(embed=emwin)
      
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == scissors and computer_pick == options[2]:
      await ctx.send("You picked: " + scissors + "\n" + "Computer picked: " + scissors)
      await ctx.send(embed=emtie)
```

I feel like it may have to do with defining the `desc = "Wins: " + str(wins) + "\n" + "Losses: " + str(losses)` right after the initial `wins = 0` & `losses = 0`, but I wouldn't know how else to arrange it in order for the embeds to work properly. I also feel like there may be an easy fix that I'm just not seeing, but if I'm not seeing it, hopefully someone else will.

Comment: You created the embed before changing the values of `wins` or `losses`, thus the embed stays exactly how you defined it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your embed after the winner is decided. I suggest creating the embed in each of the if statements checking who won. Or you could just redefine the embed in the if statements. You could also have a function for creating the embed though that is up to you. Hope this helps :D.

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked.

Comment: That's awesome @clxrity . Good luck with your project :D